# How do you pronounce "Chasch" in Jack Vance's Planet of Adventure?

Tags: pronunciation, jack-vance

A long time after reading Jack Vance's "Planet of Adventure" series, recently I've started reading it again: and again, as a non-native English speaker, I'm wondering how you are supposed to read the name of one of the alien races appearing in the novels, the Blue/Green/Old Chasch.
But, unlike the last time, now there is Internet.

In my mind, I'm reading the first "ch" in Chasch as in "chief", and the second "ch" as a "k": the result sounds similar to "Chask" and it sounds good enough to my uneducated ear.

But I realize there could be a few alternatives as well:

- the second "ch" could also be read like the first (as in "chief"): "Chas-ch"
- or it might even combine with the preceding "s" in a "sh" sound (as in "push"): "Chash".

And maybe the first "ch" isn't even the same as "chief" but a "k" sound, so the whole name is "Kask", or "Kash"...

As a non-native English speaker, it's a little confusing as there are too many alternatives that sound good enough and my ear can't decide which is the right one: so can you tell me how the Chasch are supposed to be pronounced?

Comment: Oo!  Oo!  Let's have a spirited... *discussion* about how to pronounce "schedule!" :D

Comment: More interestingly perhaps, there was a real issue with the pronunciation of the second title.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servants_of_the_Wankh#Title_changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official audiobook has it as /tʃɑ:ʃ/. I would respell it "Charsh", but if you like to pronounce your Rs, perhaps you'd prefer "Chahsh".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think of the audiobook as a way to settle my doubt. I'm just not used to them. But it would have been faster and easier.

Comment: So it appears you are non-rhotic. Inserting that silent "r" is a little misleading for me -- I heard that as "Chahsh" or even "Chosh".

Comment: @Spencer - If you want to add in all the little fiddly pronunciation phonetic symbols, you're welcome to have at it.

Comment: The IPA would be /tʃɑʃ/.

Comment: This makes me want to ask a question on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. Are you OK with that?

Comment: @Spencer - Feel free to do whatever makes you happy.

Comment: @Valorum I modified this to include the IPA symbols and clarify the rhoitcity issue. As always, feel free to roll it back.